# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable Python Object Oriented Programming

Tags: python

I am trying to create a question bank with questions and answers(True or False). I have a file called data.py with the question data:

```
question_data = [
    {"text": "A slug's blood is green.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "The loudest animal is the African Elephant.", "answer": "False"},
    {"text": "Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "The total surface area of a human lungs is the size of a football pitch.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "In West Virginia, USA, if you accidentally hit an animal with your car, you are free to take it home to eat.",
     "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "In London, UK, if you happen to die in the House of Parliament, you are entitled to a state funeral.",
     "answer": "False"},
    {"text": "It is illegal to pee in the Ocean in Portugal.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.", "answer": "False"},
    {"text": "Google was originally called 'Backrub'.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "Buzz Aldrin's mother's maiden name was 'Moon'.", "answer": "True"},
    {"text": "No piece of square dry paper can be folded in half more than 7 times.", "answer": "False"},
    {"text": "A few ounces of chocolate can to kill a small dog.", "answer": "True"}
]
```

I also have a Question class:

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, text, answer):
        self.question_text = text
        self.question_answer = answer
```

This is my code:

```
from question_model import Question
from data import question_data

question_bank = []

for question in question_data():
    q_text = question["text"]
    q_answer = question["answer"]
    new_q = Question(q_text, q_answer)
    print(new_q)
    question_bank.append(new_q)
    print(question_bank)
```

Whenever I run my code, it gives me the error:

```
for question in question_data():
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I already tried the other answers on StackOverflow, but they didn't work. What should I fix?

Comment: Remove the parentheses in the `for` loop, since `question_data` isn't a method.

Comment: `for question in question_data():` should be `for question in question_data`:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `question_data` is a list.
2. `question_data()` calls this list.
3. It's impossible to call a list (what would it mean to call a list anyway?), so you get the error.

Simply don't call the list:

```
for question in question_data:
    # do stuff
```